# Get entire node XML rather than InnerXml

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, innerxml

Given the following XML:

```
<Root>
  <Item id="1">
    <name>Foo</name>
    <status>Active</status>
  </Item>
  <Item id="2">
    <name>Bar</name>
    <status>Inactive</status>
  </Item>
</Root>
```

Let's say I have this XML in an XmlDocument object and then have the following code:

```
var nodes = xmlDocumentObject.GetElementsByTagName("Item");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
   var nodeXml = ??
}
```

I can easily get the InnerXml of each node, which for the first node would be:

```
<name>Foo</name>
<status>Active</status>
```

But how can I get the XML for the node *including* the containing tag and its attributes, such as this:

```
<Item id="1">
  <name>Foo</name>
  <status>Active</status>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [XmlNode.OuterXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) instead of `InnerXml` :

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   var nodeXml = node.OuterXml;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out why I couldn't access any either of these properties within my foreach loop (InnerXml/OuterXml). As soon as I explicitly set XmlNode as the type in the loop declaration, worked as expected. Many thanks.

Comment: `XmlNodeList` implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>` so if you use `var` in your `foreach` loop, the loop variable will be treated as an `object`, because the compiler has no way of detecting that it is a more specific type.